# IBT-2 causing voltage drop on battery but 0 voltage on motor(s)

Tags: hardware, dc-motor, robotics

I want to start by saying I know it isn't a code problem as it was working before but after I hooked up another motor controller (from a different manufacturer) it caused my motors to briefly spin up and then stop and stall.

I stopped it immediately and put 2 flyback diodes in parallel on the motors and disconnected the other speed controller but now it is producing this behavior where if I tell the left PWM to go at 100 dc and the right at 0 dc (with both enables on) it causes my ~ 10.8v voltage source to go drop to 5 volts (which is expected at full power draw).

Measuring the motor leads says 0 volts AND measuring the output motor ports on the module gives 0 as well. I am really confused. I thought the voltage would only drop if it was spinning but it's not spinning and it is pulling the same amount of voltage drop under max power.

[image: Physical view]

[image: Sketch of wiring]

I am using this motor [https://www.amazon.com/AUTOTOOLHOME-Torque-Traxxas-Wheels-Electric/dp/B01M58POHF/ref=sr_1_4?crid=3E3JXXS0NQHDT&keywords=motor+diy&qid=1653625127&sprefix=motor+diy%2Caps%2C129&sr=8-4](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B01M58POHF)

Comment: Try writing in paragraphs! That "sketch" is unintelligible use the schematic tool to post details AND include links to what is connected.

Comment: please add a focused, answerable question to your post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You picked some good parts and a very poor power source. You need something in the 10 Amp range or larger at 12V. The stall current is about 10A and full load is about 5A.  I am curious why are you adding diodes, they are built into the BTS7960. Here is a link to the data sheet: "https://www.digikey.com/htmldatasheets/production/70497/0/0/1/bts7960.html" of the BTS7960 part. You state 100V, it will not tolerate 100V, it will fry before the motor spins. The part has a minimum voltage required to operate. You are falling way below this causing it to do exactly what it should do. It does this to protect itself therefore the request for a bigger power supply. This larger power supply will ensure the internal charge pumps can provide enough power and voltage for the High Side switch gate in the BTS7960. You are below that so it is it is shutting down to protect itself. I would suggest you watch a few tutorials on the part. Your grounds need to be connected, the bridge module does that but best you do that as well. Check your logic levels, the minimum is 3V3 with a 5V logic power supply. A schematic showing all your connections as you have wired it will help us help you. Also include the Pi in the circuit.

Comment: I am not giving it a 100v power source I'm giving it 3v3. I know it worked before. The only thing that has changed is that I suppose it could have stalled my battery as one of the motor's gearbox was broken which caused that one to introduce 10amps of the stall current. 

Does that mean that just because it has voltage the batteries actually dead cause it ate up all of the juice? It was some AA's in series so that could explain it.

Oh, that was the problem. The battery shows it has 1 amp left but an aa battery gives 6 amps. Thanks!